# I have ValueError in Python script

Tags: python

Here is my short code:

```
from cv2 import cv2

img = cv2.imread("1.png")

print("Высота:"+str(img.shape[0]))
print("Ширина:" + str(img.shape[1]))
print("Количество каналов:" + str(img.shape[2]))

if img[0, 0] == (255, 255, 255):
    print("Yes")
```

But I have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\Captcha Decrypt\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    if img[0, 0] == [255, 255, 255]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `img` is a 3D array. This means that img[x,y] will be a vector, so if you try to compare it, the comparison will check the condition for each element in the vector.
As it is an array, the return will also be an array `array([True, True])` if the condition matches.
The error message you got already gave you a valid solution that you can use: call .all() on the resulting vector, which will check whether the condition is true for all elements in the array.

The correct piece of code would be:

```
if (img[0, 0] == (255, 255, 255)).all():
    print("Yes")
```

Another possible solution would be using numpy array equality (`cv2` uses numpy for arrays so it works for you too):

```
import numpy as np

if np.logical_all(img[0, 0] == (255, 255, 255)):
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your `img[0][0]` in `list(img[0][0])`:

```
from cv2 import cv2

img = cv2.imread("1.png")

print("Высота:"+str(img.shape[0]))
print("Ширина:" + str(img.shape[1]))
print("Количество каналов:" + str(img.shape[2]))

if list(img[0][0]) == [255, 255, 255]:
    print("Yes")

else:
    print("No")
```